# Unstable FPS while playing Metro Exodus - Enhanced Edition

Tags: performance, metro-exodus

Update:

In recent couple of days, I have found inconsistence GPU power used by this game. please refer to screen shot1, which has gpu power of only 54 watts and hence very low fps. In screen shot2, gpu power is 119 watts and hence much better fps. These are taken with the same system. Screen shot 3 shows in Witcher 3, the gpu power is also the normal at 125 watts and the fps is great. It looks like (to me) this still a game issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I just started playing Metro Exodus - Enhanced Edition. My laptop setup is:

Note: GPU is on 130 W!

[image: Screenshot of system information]

Video settings in the game is 1920x1080 on Ultra, and others are mostly set to default. I find the FPS is not stable, sometimes a lot more than 60 fps (90 or higher), but sometimes quite low at around 20 fps. I have changed the various video settings and it only changes the FPS a little bit, but I've still got this huge inconsistency in fps. I have even tried resolution of 800X600 and that doesn't improve the FPS a lot. I have even tested with the Metro Exodus Enhanced Edition benchmark tool and tried different settings and it always returns around 53 - 59 average FPS. So what could be the issue? Most of the games I have played on this laptop have excellent FPS. I don't think my setup is too low-end for this game.

Comment: Really, it feels like your computer has something that bottlenecks it. I had that for an old PC where I could run everything on High and keep a solid 60. But turn on even the most basic of shadows and I would fall to 10FPS. So my suggestion for you would be to put every single slider to the lowest setting one by one, and play a small amount see if it still has drops. The moment you put something to low/off and your drops stop, thats the thing your graphics card struggle with.

Comment: Also important to note, games will always vary in FPS, and its not your PC at fault. Have a tranquil moment in a building, where shadows are simple... 90 FPS. Got a fight with 63 explosions and 200 effects going on, that will kill your FPS to 20 or so. Also, the point that other games have excellent FPS doesn't say much. what causes drops might just be that their particular engine process has a problem with your particular card or something, but I don't have enough knowledge on the subject to tell.

Comment: But yeah, sorry I can't help you much, but if you poke around you might discover that there are some things where your graphics card struggle and next time you see those drops, you will know exactly what to turn off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems a different issue. i have added updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I installed and played Cyberpunk 2077 today and used the default graphic settings of ray tracing ultra at 1080 P, the fps is around 50 - 58 avg, not too bad actually. The GPU power being used is over 110 watts. So it proves the GPU is ok, so I am pretty sure it's the Metro exodus enhanced edition somehow not utilizing the full power of the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably either thermal throttling or the system is switching from the 3060 to the GPU on the CPU die. You can try setting the nvidia settings to "maximum performance" under "power" and/or set the dedicated 3060 as preferred under the game profile. Also affirm that the Windows Power Configuration is set to "fans first" for thermal handling.

Comment: Also check to ensure your laptop power connection is OK: I have seen worn AC connectors cause a laptop to cycle between "plugged in" and "not" when moved or jostled

Comment: Thanks, but it seems not a power issue or others.

Comment: it is definitely throttling from the screenshots. I guess the question is "why". Again, "fans always on" is what you should be looking for. THe GPU will throttle *first* to reduce heat

Comment: Should have read: "Otherwise the GPU will throttle first..."